# Remove rectangle from image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr

How to remove the outer rectangle from this image? If there should be other rectangles inside the outer rectangle they should stay untoched. Only the outer rectagnel should be removed

Below I have some code which can detect the entire rectangle but how to mask only the outer rectangle and remove it?

Have attached the input and what I expect as output

OpenCV `4.5.1`

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

```
// g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>

const int
    HIERARCHY_NEXT              = 0,
    HIERARCHY_PREV              = 1,
    HIERARCHY_CHILD             = 2,
    HIERARCHY_PARENT            = 3,
    SHAPE_UNKNOWN               = -1,
    SHAPE_RECT                  = 0;

struct Contours {
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
};

Contours find_contours(const cv::Mat& m, int retrieve_type, bool fetch_hierarchy=true){
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    
    if(fetch_hierarchy){
        cv::findContours(m, contours, hierarchy, retrieve_type, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    }
    else{
        cv::findContours(m, contours, retrieve_type, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    }
    
    Contours con;
    con.contours    = contours;
    con.hierarchy   = hierarchy;
    
    return con;
}

int detect_contour_shape(const std::vector<cv::Point>& contour, double precision=0.02, bool convex=true){
    std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
    cv::approxPolyDP(contour, approx, cv::arcLength(contour, true) * precision, true);
    
    if(convex && !cv::isContourConvex(approx)){
        return SHAPE_UNKNOWN;
    }
    
    switch(approx.size()){
        case 4:
            return SHAPE_RECT;
        
        default:
            return SHAPE_UNKNOWN;
    }
}

bool is_contour_top_with_children(Contours contours, int i){
    return contours.hierarchy[i][HIERARCHY_PARENT] == -1 && contours.hierarchy[i][HIERARCHY_CHILD] != -1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cv::Mat
        src     = cv::imread("input.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),
        mask    = cv::Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1);
    
    Contours contours = find_contours(src, cv::RETR_TREE);
    
    //  Filter contours
    if(!contours.hierarchy.empty()){
        for(int i = 0; i >= 0; i = contours.hierarchy[i][HIERARCHY_NEXT]){
            //  Contour has no parent (top-level contour) and has children
            if(is_contour_top_with_children(contours, i)){
                if(detect_contour_shape(contours.contours[i]) == SHAPE_RECT){
                    cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours.contours[i]);
                    
                    std::cout << rect << '\n';
                    cv::drawContours(mask, contours.contours, i, cv::Scalar(255), cv::FILLED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    cv::imwrite("mask.png", mask);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use the coordinates or it must run automatically?

Comment: @YScharf it must be 100% automatic

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the largest contour and draw a thick black rectangle around it. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Read the input image:
    std::string imageName = "D://opencvImages//LSmPY.png";
    cv::Mat inputImage =  cv::imread( imageName );

    // Convert BGR to Gray:
    cv::Mat grayImage;
    cv::cvtColor( inputImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY );

    // Extract external contours:
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours( grayImage, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

    // Loop through all contours:
    for( int i = 0; i< (int)contours.size(); i++ ) {
        
        // Get contour area:
        double contourArea = cv::contourArea( contours[i], false );

        // Only process the contour if it is above a certain area:
        double minArea = 100000;
        if (contourArea > minArea){
            // Get bounding rectangle:
            cv::Rect boundingRectangle = cv::boundingRect( contours[i] );

            int rectX = boundingRectangle.x;
            int rectY = boundingRectangle.y;
            int rectWidth = boundingRectangle.x + boundingRectangle.width;
            int rectHeight = boundingRectangle.y + boundingRectangle.height;

            // Draw a thick black rectangle around contour:
            int rectangleThickness = 10;
            cv::rectangle( inputImage, cv::Point(rectX, rectY), cv::Point(rectWidth, rectHeight), cv::Scalar(0,0,0), rectangleThickness );
            
            cv::imshow( "Out Image", inputImage );
            cv::waitKey(0);

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output image:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First use `Sobel filter` in the `x-axis` to find just the vertical lines.
Follow [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) for more details on the `Sobel filter` operator.

```
 cv::Mat src_gray = cv::imread("input.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),
 Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

Then loop over columns to find the lines with a high count of white pixels.

```
int threshWhite = 100
int colNum1, colNum2 = 0, 0;
for(int i = 0; i < grad_x.cols; i++)
{
   
    int numWhite = cv::countNonZero(grad_x.col(i))
    if (numWhite  > threshWhite ){
    colNum1 = i;
    colNum2 = grad_x.cols - i;
    break;
    }
}
```

Note:
Given that the distance from margin to outer lines are symmetric.

For the upper line of the rectangle, do the same with two adjustments:

```
Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 0, 1, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

Sobel on the y-axis to find horizontal line

```
int threshWhite = 100
int rowNum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < grad_x.rows; i++)
{

    int numWhite = cv::countNonZero(grad_x.row(i))
    if (numWhite  > threshWhite ){
    rowNum = i;

    break;
    }
}
```

This answer is just a suggestion on one way to approach this scenario.
As @clarkk pointed out, "this answer is not robust". Thanks @clarkk again.

Some more suggestions to improve robustness:

Look for a line by comparing two lines back to current line. When hitting a line, the difference in `countNonZero` should be high.

```
for ...

int numNonWhite = cv::countNonZero(grad_x.row(i))
int numWhite = cv::countNonZero(grad_x.row(i+2))
int diff = numWhite - numNonWhite ;
if (diff > diffThresh)
   ...
```

Comment: I only want to find the outer rectangle.. If there are any rectangles inside they should stay in the image

Comment: Added break to stop at outer lines.

Comment: I have not tested it, but if you only count which column has the highest count of white pixels this solution is not robust enogh

Comment: Not robust enough! Agreed! Thanks for point that out @clarkk. Suggestions to improve robustness added.